# Calculate the height of a person on a picture

Tags: geometry, triangles, image-processing

I am experimenting with an app to calculate the length of a person with the camera of my phone. I put my phone on the ground against the wall and make a picture. This situation is shown in the image below *(side view)*:

[image]

The following variables are known:

- The pitch of the phone ***p*** (20°)
- The vertical field of view of the camera (60°)
- The distance of the person to the wall (2 meters)

Now I want to calculate the length of ***l***.

---

The picture taken by the camera looks like this *(front view)*:

[image]

From this picture I can read the following variables:

- The height of the image is 1000 pixels
- The height of the person on the image is 750 pixels

---

Although, it must be noted that the proportions on the image will not reflect the real person due to the perspective of the camera as can be seen here *(side view)*:

[image]

---

I'm not sure if all of this information is relevant or if there is anything missing. In that case, please let me know.

I'm currently stuck with this problem and hope that someone can guide me in the right direction. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You gave a distance from the phone to the person, but it isn't clear how much the lines project behind this person before the "projected person on image" is formed.

Comment: @Cure Thank you for your comment. I am not fully sure about what this distance would be either. I updated my question to improve the description of that image.

Comment: There’s not enough information here to recover even affine properties of the scene (e.g., ratios of lengths of line segments). Since you’re working on a phone app, it should be possible to recover the camera’s calibration matrix, with which you can measure all sorts of things in the image. Barring that, you’ll need to glean more information from the image itself. For instance, if you can find the vanishing line of the ground plane, a vertical vanishing point and the actual height of any other object in the scene, you can compute the person’s height.